# Is it possible to restore access to github account with pswd, login and active session?

Tags: github

I have a github account, that I can sign in in the browser.

The 2FA enabled for the account, however, the phone, where the TOTP app was configured, now is unavailable.

Now, I can't access the github account anywhere else except the browser, because any authorization ask me to open TOTP, but I have no TOTP as the phone was broken.

I have tried to add more ways for 2FA via github settings (screen below), but any of the actions requires me to pass 2FA with TOTP which (as already have been mentioned several times) is impossible

[image]

So I can't sign in, and can't change auth methods. Can I do smth to sign in from another browser, or github mobile app, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that file on my PC
[image]

to pass verification, then I was able to register new authenticator app from my phone.

then I have added one more method for 2FA with SMS.